# How to fix rails Couldn't find Post without an ID Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and little know of ruby, I have just stared tutorial from Rails Guide 4.0. Everything was going fine just stuck on one Error : Couldn't find Post without an ID.

I did everything as in Rails Guide Getting Started Of Rails.

Here is code from rails guide :

```
def show
  @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

and Here is View Code :

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @posts.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @posts.text %>
</p>
```

After this code rails guide tell you should finally be able to create new posts. Visit localhost:3000/posts/new and give it a try!. But after create new post it showing me error.

I thought it could be issue because i didn't created index action yet so i done with index, After index action when i try to visit this address normally it should display all record from database but rather then display record showing same error : Couldn't find Post without an ID

I tried too many posts on stackoverflow but all related to some other actions that are not useful for me.

Please help me to fix this issue, i am just thinking it shouldn't be because i am following rails guide.

I am following rails getting started guide as it said i added index action and show action. So as in book it said with index action when you visit this address /posts you should see all posts and when you create new post it will redirect to show last post you entered,

I was using redirect_to @post but that comes with error i stuck then i use `redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id`

it's working when i create a new post then it redirect to /posts?id=last_inserted_id but as i saw other scaffold address should be posts/1 or etc and when i visit /posts it should show all the posts action defined as index in controller.

```
routes.rb

<code>
  Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  root "welcome#new"

  resource :posts
</code>
```

Controller :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @post = Post.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #index.html.erb
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #show.html.erb
    end
  end

  def new

  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new post_params
    @post.save
    redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :message)
    end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: 1. show how you build a link to show action (insert your code from view). 2. If you define routes for posts NOT as `resources :posts` you should show your routes as well.

Comment: 1 : I am adding action to address bar like this : /posts/etc
2 : I am using resources :posts

Comment: like `/posts/1` ? and what do you see in log server (or in `development.log`)?

Comment: this error when writes /posts/1 --- 

No route matches [GET] "/posts/1"

Comment: smth is wrong with routing. What exactly you write in address bar whan you get error `Couldn't find Post without an ID`? Post your `routes.rb` - because `resources :posts` should add route for `127.0.0.1:3000/posts/1` and you can get error `Post with id=1 not found` but not `No route matches...`

Comment: Just edited my question as in comment box it's showing too many lines, please read at end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `resources :posts` not `resource`!

`resources` generates "full" CRUD - 7 actions http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources

when `resource` generates routes uniq resource (without action `show`) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource

Comment: Thanks you for solving my problem,